# I want to calculate UILabel with attributeText use chinese, but the label height not like english;

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

this is the height contain chinese;

[image]

this is the height contain english

how to delete blank space by chinese

[image]

delete this blank

Answer (score 0):

You adjust spacing property shown in screenshot of your `UILabel`[image]